# git rebase fatal: Needed a single revision

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have a branch of a public repository and I am trying to update my branch with the current commits from the original repository:

```
$ git fetch <remote>
remote: Counting objects: 24, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Total 20 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (20/20), done.
From git://github.com/path_to/repo
  9b70165..22127d0  master     -> $/master
$ git rebase <remote>
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream <remote>
```

The `<remote>` is in place of my remote name and is not actually my remote name. The documentation on this error seems to be a bit loose.

Comment: I got this error for an unrelated reason - using "git rebase --interactive c4e9c94^" from a Windows command prompt. It prompted me "More?", and regardless of how it answered the prompt, it said "fatal: needed a single revision". But when I ran the same command from bash, it worked fine.

Comment: As a side note, for me in addition to having upstream branch listed with "remote" I had to fetch the specific branch that I wanted to rebase on. "git fetch <upstream> master". Fetching just <upstream>  with "git fetch <upstream>" still would give me this error.

Comment: I'm somewhat disappointed that the *only* answer here that describes what's really the problem, and describes the remedy that allows you to use `git rebase <remote>` as you should be able to, has only one upvote. The accepted answer is a workaround.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You need to provide the name of a branch (or other commit identifier), not the name of a remote to `git rebase`.

E.g.:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

not:

```
git rebase origin
```

Note, although `origin` should resolve to the the ref `origin/HEAD` when used as an argument where a commit reference is required, it seems that not every repository gains such a reference so it may not (and in your case doesn't) work. It pays to be explicit.

Comment: The latter should actually work - `origin` in ref context is interpreted as `origin/HEAD`. I've seen repositories end up not knowing what `origin/HEAD` is, though...

Comment: @Jefromi: I afraid that I don't believe you, I've just tried `git rebase origin` on a test repository (where `origin` has a `HEAD`) and I get the OP's error. The documentation for rebase doesn't say that a remote name is valid for the `<upstream>`.

Comment: @Charles: Well, it may be a bug? `git rev-parse origin` works, as does `git rebase origin` in my git.git clone (in up-to-date, fast-forward, and true rebase case, including interactive).

Comment: @Jefromi: Can you `git describe` your `HEAD`?

Comment: @Charles: up to date, v1.7.4-rc3! I'm not terribly eager to do a bisect looking for this one...

Comment: Hm, and the [relevant documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions) (third bullet) looks like it was added in October 2006, so it seems like it always should've worked.

Comment: @Jefromi: Are you sure you don't have a ref or branch called origin? I've tried with v1.7.4-rc3 and I still get exactly the same error message.

Comment: I definitely don't. `find .git -name origin` produces the refs and reflog directories, and the packed refs don't have one either. I tried this in test repos, too - couple test commits, just enough to get the three basic rebase cases, and it works fine there too. I do think your answer is pretty definitely correct; you and James just appear to be having a similar issue.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, but isn't the default ref spec for remotes: `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` which shouldn't keep a copy of `refs/HEAD` ?

Comment: That's a great point - it looks like it's not generally fetched. It definitely has to be inspected when you clone, to determine your initial HEAD. I can deduce by removing and modifying it that subsequent fetches/remote updates don't refresh it. `git remote show origin` does attempt to show the remote's HEAD, though in my tests, whenever I check out a new branch in origin, it ends up thinking remote HEAD is ambiguous... it looks like this isn't terribly robust, whatever it is. Here's a script demonstrating that it works initially: http://pastebin.com/0ucBvqzm

Comment: @Jefromi: Perhaps the initial `HEAD` is fetched automagically in newer clones, my git clone that I tested with is quite old.

Comment: Aha, and here's [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614565/preview-changes-on-bare-repo-doesnt-work-correctly) where I learned that this *should* work. (see Jakub's comment.) I have since then been using `git log ..origin` quite a lot!

Answer (score 35):

Check that you **spelled the branch name correctly**. I was rebasing a story branch (i.e. `branch_name`) and forgot the story part. (i.e. `story/branch_name`) and then git spit this error at me which didn't make much sense in this context.

Comment: Exactly this. Typed `featureName` when the branch is actually named `features/featureName`

Comment: Also a good idea to look for simple typos more thoroughly. I accidentally swapped two letters when creating branch and this typo was really hard to spot.

Answer (score 31):

I ran into `fatal: Needed a single revision` and realized I didn't fetch the upstream before trying to rebase.  All I needed was to `git fetch upstream` first.

Comment: i got this error "fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository"

Comment: @SyedAliShahzil, it seems like you have a general configuration error. I would copy and paste your local .git/config, the command you're trying to perform, and the error message and ask chatgpt. Otherwise, try searching Stackoverflow or Google and get some help that way.

Answer (score 12):

The issue is that you branched off a branch off of.... where you are trying to rebase to. You can't rebase to a branch that does not contain the commit your current branch was originally created on.

I got this when I first rebased a local branch X to a pushed one Y, then tried to rebase a branch (first created on X) to the pushed one Y.

Solved for me by rebasing to X.

I have no problem rebasing to remote branches (potentially not even checked out), provided my current branch stems from an ancestor of that branch.

Comment: You can rebase to such a branch with `--onto`. Everything descends from *some* common ancestor (for normal repositories), so that isn't the problem. I've gotten this error from trying to rebase onto `foo` when I had not yet created the branch to track `origin/foo`.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs when your repository does not have the default branch set for the remote. You can use the `git remote set-head` command to modify the default branch, and thus be able to use the remote name instead of a specified branch in that remote.

To query the remote (in this case `origin`) for its `HEAD` (typically `master`), and set that as the default branch:

```
$ git remote set-head origin --auto
```

If you want to use a different default remote branch locally, you can specify that branch:

```
$ git remote set-head origin new-default
```

Once the default branch is set, you can use just the remote name in `git rebase <remote>` and any other commands instead of explicit `<remote>/<branch>`.

Behind the scenes, this command updates the reference in `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.

```
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

See the [git-remote man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) for further details.

Comment: @VladimirShefer rewrote the entire answer to use `git remote set-head` instead of messing with `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` directly.

Comment: Also, I think this answers the original question better than the accepted answer, which is just a workaround to the root cause.

Comment: thank you for you answer. It is much better now! I have deleted my downvote mark.

Answer (score 2):

For me, to specify branch helps.

```
  1 [submodule "test/gtest"]
  2     path = test/gtest
  3     url = ssh://git@git.github.com/google/googletest.git
  4     branch = main
```

Answer (score 0):

`git submodule deinit --all -f`
worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

$ git rebase upstream/master

fatal: Needed a single revision

invalid upstream usptream/master**

So I tried ***$ git rebase remotes/upstream/master*** and it works for me.