# How to build docker source code after modifying it?

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu-14.04

We're trying to change in the docker source code and re-build it to see the changes

**Problem** we're not able to build docker form the source code itself.
we tried: `make` in the docker directory but we ended with the error(after initializing git by `git init`):

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
make: *** [binary] Error 128
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798080/git-rebase-fatal-needed-a-single-revision) didn't help, since we got the error:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream origin/master
```

We checked the issue in docker community, and they suggested to clone the directory form the docker repository and re-build again, but we still can't `make` the source.

**Question** 
How to build the source code after we modified it?

Comment: "but we still can't make the source." care to add a bit more detail there? Whet error message do you see? the same one?

Comment: yes, the same message

Comment: What does `git log` return in the folder where you do 'make'?

Comment: `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`

Comment: That is why: you need to clone the repo which has the source, and make sure git log does give you its full history. You don't have to do any local giti init. Just a `git clone https://github.com/docker/docker && cd docker && git log && make`

Comment: What happens if you don't do "git init"?

Comment: @Noamiko: we get the error which is found on line 79 in `docker-master/hack/make.sh` : "`error: .git directory missing and DOCKER_GITCOMMIT not specified
Please either build with the .git directory accessible, or specify the
exact (--short) commit hash you are building using DOCKER_GITCOMMIT for
future accountability in diagnosing build issues.  Thanks!`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions in [this link](http://docs.docker.com/opensource/code/):

> 1. Get the software you need.
>
>    This explains how to install a couple of tools used in our
>      development environment. What you need (or don’t need) might surprise
>      you.
> 2. Configure Git and fork the repo.
>
>    Your Git configuration can make it easier for you to contribute.
>      Configuration is especially key if are new to contributing or to
>      Docker.
> 3. Learn to work with the Docker development container.
>
>    Docker developers run docker in docker. If you are a geek, this is a
>      pretty cool experience.
> 4. Claim an issue to work on.
>
>    We created a filter listing all open and unclaimed issues for
>      Docker.
> 5. Work on the issue.
>
>    If you change or add code or docs to a project, you should test your
>      changes as you work. This page explains how to test in our development
>      environment.
>
>    Also, remember to always sign your commits as you work! To sign your
>      commits, include the -s flag in your commit like this:
>
>    ```
>    $ git commit -s -m "Add commit with signature example"
>    ```
>
>    If you don't sign Gordon will get you!
> 6. Create a pull request.
>
>    If you make a change to fix an issue, add reference to the issue in
>      the pull request.