# How to rebase the fork derived from another Git fork

Tags: git, rebase

I am using following setup:

1. public repo is forked as repo1
2. repo2 is fork of repo1

Following commands don't work if I am trying to rebase the repo2:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/laanwj/etna_viv.git
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```

The last command gives following error:

> 9$ git rebase upstream/master fatal: Needed a single revision invalid
>   upstream upstream/master

Comment: What is the name of the remote `<remote>`? And what is the name of the upstream, `<remote>/<branch>`? It seems that you mixed the two notions.

Comment: Does `upstream/master` actually exist?

Answer (score 1):

That happens when the branch onto which you are rebasing has no commit (nothing was fetched from `upstream/master`), as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5481551/6309).

Make sure first that, once fetched `upstream/master` does exist, with at least one commit.