# Git gui: how to push to a remote branch?

Tags: git, github, remote-branch

I have cloned a repository from github and checked out a remote branch.  I made a change to the remote branch, committed it, but then when I try to push the change back to the remote branch I get the message "Everything is up-to-date".  What am I doing wrong here?  Plus, it doesn't let me push to the branch, the only option is master.

I'm using git gui, and checking out the branch was very simple.  I just can't figure out how to push the change back to the repository.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022726/git-push-on-a-remote-branch

Comment: what is being shown when you type `git status`?

Comment: # on branch remotebranch
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line,

```
git push -u origin branch-name
```

Now in git gui you should have that branch come up

Comment: you're right, i do see it now but it still tells me that everything is up to date... any idea why its not pushing the changes?

Comment: The command line pushed it. So now it's up to date. Check on github

Comment: I don't see any changes on github under my actions, nor in the repository :(

Comment: Did you pick the other branch from the drop down?

Comment: it turned out the change I made was lost somehow, maybe by switching between branches or something, I had to make the change and commit it again, then pushed it and it worked :) Thanks!  I wonder what happened to my previous commit haha...

Comment: If you don't use --force with commands or reset --hard you shouldn't lose anything. As long as you committed, you can check the reflog.

Comment: hey you're right... the reflog shows that the commits are both there... the first one shows that it was moved from a hash to the remotebranch and the second one shows that it was moved from master to origin/remotebranch... i still don't get why it didn't push and show in github the first time, i'd love an explanation if you have an idea?